# CKeditor & MediaWiki 1.15 or 1.16 beta

Tags: ckeditor, mediawiki

Has any body successfully integrated ckeditor 3.x with mediawiki

I have followed the instructions for fckeditor, thinking it may be the same for ckeditor too, but that doesn't helps.

it either doesn't loads the wiki at all or doesn't loads the ckeditor.

any thoughts / suggestions or a step by step to do this would be very helpful.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I see nobody has answered so far. I haven't done this either but will do so in the next month or two so please check back then.  I do remember that I did a lot of configuring and testing before integrating FCK into our older MW (1.13.2).

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks so much for your response, I have even tried contacting CKeditor support and they didn't gave me a satisfying answer.
I will look forward to assist you on this by testing or experimenting with Mediawiki - ckeditor.

With FCKEditor for mediawiki, its just a line in Localsettings.php and the extension itself goes into /yourwiki/extensionsfolder/

I have used 1.1.x, currently 1.15.4.
Kind Regards
Rihatum

Comment: Hi Rihatum - we're using MW 1.15.4 and FCK $Rev$ 2008 - if this matches what you're looking for I'll come back with a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is old but I've been looking to integrate CKEditor for a while now and there is very little information concerning this on the net!  For anyone else who might be looking:

I found this on MediaWiki in FCKEditor section of the [WYSIWYG_editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/WYSIWYG_editor#Proof_of_concept%3a_WYSIWYG_Editors) page:

> Ontoprise's halo team is maintaining a production quality integration
>   of MediaWiki and CKEditor: [Extension:WYSIWYG](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWYSIWYG).

I installed it on our MediaWiki (v.1.16) and so far it works like a charm!

Comment: Hi Tania Gobeil, thank you for your input - it is highly appreciated, I mean i literally had forgotten and only came back this morning here searching for ckeditor and mediawiki - can you elaborate a bit as to how you installed / and any other obstacles u faced ? was it just as easy as extracting it in extensions and then calling it from Localsettings.php ? Will be grateful - Many thanks - will post here back if I am unsuccessful :-) |Thanks so Much !!!

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this as well, and found this from the MW users site:
http://www.mwusers.com/forums/showthread.php?16957-CKEditor-with-MediaWiki

> To use ckeditor with mediawiki:
>
> download and unpack the source ckeditor package place it in the
>   extensions directory of mediawiki add the following lines to the end
>   of mediawiki LocalSettings.php:
>
> ```
> require_once("$IP/extensions/ckeditor/ckeditor.php");
> $wgHooks['EditPage::showEditForm:initial'][] = 'showEditForm';
> function showEditForm($form) {
>    global $wgOut; 
>    $wgOut->addScriptFile('/extensions/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' );
>    $script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> window.onload = function() {
>        CKEDITOR.replace( 'wpTextbox1' ); }; if ( window.removeEventListener )
>        window.removeEventListener( 'load', mwSetupToolbar, false ) ; else if
>        ( window.detachEvent ) window.detachEvent( 'onload', mwSetupToolbar )
>        </script>";
>    $wgOut->addHTML($script);
>    return true; 
> }
> ```

If someone is able to confirm this works or not, please comment/reply. (Apologies that I can't fully confirm this solution at present).